Were Soviet doctors and nurses actually as callous as "Voices from Chernobyl" portrays in the prologue?
In the prologue to Voices from Chernobyl, Svetlana Alexievich includes a story from the wife of one of the firemen, Vasily Ivanovich Ignatenko, who put out the initial fire after the meltdown at Chernobyl. She recounts, among other things:

The Soviets manipulated the families of the firemen to get them out of the way so that they could secretly airlift them to Moscow
She had to bribe hospital staff to be allowed to see her husband
She was told on more than one occasion that it was no longer her husband (or even a human) in the hospital room - just a radioactive threat
When she commented to the head nurse that her husband was dying, she simply replied "Well, what did you expect?" based on the amount of radiation he had been exposed to.

Reading this, I was rather shocked by the sheer callousness of the Soviet medical system. The book portrays the doctors and nurses as dehumanizing and callous towards both the firemen and their families.
How accurate was this portrayal? Would this have been normal behavior for Soviet hospital staff?

It might sound callous to a westerner, but it is also honest. Given the general misery of the life in the USSR, most people likely simply didn't pay attention to the minor niceties that a westerner find offensive - the tone of voice, crude figures of speech, politically incorrect language.

Having been exposed to both soviet and western medicine, this doesn't seem to be a soviet type thing. Medical professionals generally try to follow protocol, for very very good reasons. Try to see your husband when he's in contaminated/infectious ward in a western hospital... (or FFS, "outside of visiting hours" in normal ward), and you get less than warm response. Try to harrass a busy nurse trying to take care of 5 patients and she won't always be warm and polite.

Dear new users: answer the question. Don't just relate your experiences about eastern Europe today.

It is a shame that Alexievich did not interview any of the nurses and doctors. The incident must have been hugely stressful for them too - inadequate hospitals suddenly flooded with large numbers of desperately ill people, no protocols in place to deal with radioactive contamination, and so on. Some of the short-temper is understandable.

I had relatives including my wife dying under traumatic circumstances and "that is no longer your wife", and "what do you expect" were pretty much things the western (German) doctors and nurses said to me. So I wonder if this is more about being unfamiliar with violent death than something specific Eastern.

@Claradiazsanchez I don't know whether she did or not yet, I'm only an hour or two into the audiobook so far. You do bring up a great point, though - it would have been great to have gotten some of their perspectives too. I hope she does include some of their perspectives.

I second DVK and Herr Pierstorff. While it is sad that she was not able to visit her husband, the nurses and doctors did nothing wrong, and the (many) medical professionals I have worked with over the years would almost certainly have responded similarly. The only difference is that they might phrase it slightly more nicely; see Petr's answer.

The third example is more blatantly (possibly maliciously) dishonest than it is callous.  Though wielding that level of dishonesty against a grieving family member certainly is.  The first example would have been the government's doing and unrelated to any subsequent actions of any doctors and nurses.

I have not read Voices from Chernobyl, but overall what you describe does not seen overly unusual. In Soviet times in many situations the employees were not much sympathetic and polite towards the clients, often actually rude, especially if the clients asked something unusual. Probably this was because the salary of the employees did not depend on what the clients think of them, and they often treated the clients as a distraction. And the clients did not have much choice anyway in the absence of market competition.
In modern Russian, there is even a word "совок" that means (derogatory) Soviet Union, or anything associated with it, and in particular this specific attitude towards clients.
Also, in Soviet Union (and to an extent in modern Russia) people preferred and still prefer to say what they think without 'softening the blow' — or, to put it another way, modern US culture requires a lot of softening the speech, much more that many other cultures. (I believe there was even a Wikipedia page about this difference in cultures, but I can't think of correct search terms...)

The Soviets manipulated the families of the firemen to get them out of the way so that they could secretly airlift them to Moscow

This may be explained by the reasons of secrecy. If the government wants to keep the actual situation secret, it is not surprising that they will be lying or manipulating even the relatives of victims.

She had to bribe hospital staff to be allowed to see her husband

This seems very plausible to me. Soviet hospitals had very strict rules regarding visiting the patients (partially this is still in place in modern Russia), e.g. there may be a very specific time when visits were allowed, or visits would be completely prohibited in case of severe condition of a patient (in fact, the latter sounds sensible). However, AFAIU, small bribes were rather common in Soviet Union, so even if the visit was prohibited, one could bribe the person in charge to be let in.

She was told on more than one occasion that it was no longer her husband (or even a human) in the hospital room - just a radioactive threat

This may be an example of such rudeness that I mentioned above, but to my ear it may also sound as an attempt to reason and may be to stop the wife from seeing her husband — maybe an unprofessional and blunt attempt, but the situation was very unusual, and I doubt that Soviet doctors did have much training in relating bad news to the relatives. (Imagine a zombie apocalypse to which nobody was prepared, a wife wanting to see her husband who is a zombie and a danger now, and somebody stopping her and telling that this is no more her husband... Would you call it callous?)

When she commented to the head nurse that her husband was dying, she simply replied "Well, what did you expect?" based on the amount of radiation he had been exposed to.

This is a typical совок attitude.

You have asked two questions, so there are two answers.
In the reverse order:

Would this have been normal behavior for Soviet hospital staff?

Not at all. A governing principle of Soviet deontology was that the less a patient (or family) knows, the better. It was against the book to disclose terminal conditions.

How accurate was this portrayal?

Very accurate. The Chernobyl situation was different since nobody was prepared to deal with it, and the book was put aside.
I'm sorry I don't have any documents or other sources to support this. Consider it anecdotal evidence.

"Not at all"??  I think you mean "Yes, absolutely" it was normal procedure.

@RonJohn what is your "Yes, absolutely" based on?

The rest of the paragraph: "A governing principle of Soviet deontology was that the less a patient (or family) knows, the better. It was against the book to disclose terminal conditions."  It was normal behavior for Soviet doctors and nurses to act how was listed in OP's four bullet points.

@RonJohn I think you didn't read OP's four bullet points, as none of them states that the doctors withheld information about the state of the patient to their family—quite the opposite, actually. So that's not at all in line with "the governing principle of Soviet deontology".

I have never dealt with Soviet or Russian medical personnel (and, meaning no offense, I hope it stays that way), but this sort of callousness crops up all over, unfortunately, especially in cases like this where the victims are believed to pose dangers to visitors. Doris Kelley, whose husband, Cecil, was fatally irradiated in a criticality incident at Los Alamos National Laboratory, was not informed of the accident until after her husband had died, even though he lived for almost a day and a half. Though Doris was pressured into not suing with promised compensation that never arrived, she and her daughter sued the pathologist who had performed Cecil's autopsy (who claimed God gave him permission to remove 3.6kg of Cecil's organs), eventually settling for over $10 million. I don't have anyone on record telling Doris her husband was no longer human, but I'd expect it's what they were thinking.
Point is, it's credible behaviour not only for Soviet medical staff, but for medical staff of any nationality in irradiation incidents. Bear in mind, too, that the no-visitors policy was likely imposed from above, as victims of radiation poisoning really can be dangerously radioactive, and it's easier, emotionally, to suppress one's compassion when one is ordered not to be compassionate.
